# How far off the ground PVC conduit be attached to house?

Tags: electrical

I am installing a hot tub disconnect going from outside panel 50' to disconnect. How far from the ground can I mount the PVC to the house?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: PVC can be run up the side of a skyscraper if you like. It's not clear what your concern is.

Comment: My concern is if there is code that states how far from the ground you need to be. I would like to run 2' from ground

Comment: for how low: I'm pretty sure you're allowed to bury it.

Answer (score 3):

You can run the conduit up, or along the side of, the house at any level.

Below 8 feet in height, it must be Schedule 80 (not Schedule 40) as it is defined as being "exposed to damage." That may require a trip to "a real electrical supply," as most home centers/box stores don't stock that.

Depending on relative price of the two types, it *may* be less expensive to run it up to the eaves, and be able to use Schedule 40 for the long sideways run, only needing Schedule 80 for the parts below 8 feet. But it's perfectly fine to run it at 2 feet, so long as it's Schedule 80.

Comment: Didn't realize you needed sched 80. I think best is to bury and go get 1 10' length of sched 80 and use my other 6 underground. Thanks for stopping me from making that huge mistake! I.ve only used 80 when I ran conduit ubder a parking lot.